# Optimization of SOM grid and number of metaclusters flowSOM

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, large-data, bioinformatics

I am currently attempting to optimize the dimension of the SOM grid, as well as the number of metaclusters for some flow cytometry data in R, using the well documented flowSOM package.

From what I have seen so far, the dimension of the SOM grid as well as the number of metaclusters, two primordial parameters for the flowSOM analysis, are chosen somewhat arbitrarily, with the help of domain knowledge on the cells relevant the experiment in question.

I am trying to use the silhouette method in order to optimize for the dimension of the SOM grid, as well as the number of metaclusters, however I keep on negative values for all of the different SOM dimensions, even though I am trying a large range (5x5 to 25x25).

Please find the code below:

```r
library(parallel)
library(dplyr)
#Specify the FlowSOM parameters
SOM_x <- 5:25
SOM_y <- 5:25
n_meta <- 15 # Will start w this while optimising the SOM grid size !@
#n_meta should be chosen with some sort of bioogical apriori knowledge
#of the cellular population being studied

seed <- 2023
scaling <- FALSE

#GetMetaclusters() FlowSOMSubset()
#Will do this in parallel to make this faster::
num_cores <- detectCores() # 8 !!!!
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(FlowSOM)
  library(flowCore)
})
clusterExport(cl, c("SOM_x", "SOM_y","n_meta","seed","scaling","agg",
                    "markers_of_interest"))

parLapply(cl, SOM_x, function(som){
    #Create FlowSOM object with specified grid size and num of metaclusters
    flow_som_obj <- FlowSOM(
      input = agg, #aggregated flowframes, including all time points
      scale = scaling,
      colsToUse = markers_of_interest,
      seed = seed,
      xdim = som, ydim = som,
      nClus = n_meta
    )

  return(flow_som_obj %>% GetClusters())
}) -> results

names(results) <- paste0("SOM_", SOM_x)

# Evaluate the clustering results using metrics like silhouette scores
idx <- sample(nrow(agg@exprs), 20000)
dist(agg@exprs[idx,]) -> disto #only need to generate this once::

silhouette_scores <- list()
for (result_name in names(results)) {
  clustering <- results[[result_name]] %>% as.numeric()
  #use subsample for silhouette calculation::
  silhouette_scores[[result_name]] <- silhouette(clustering[idx], 
                                                 disto)
}

avg_silhouettes <- sapply(silhouette_scores, function(i){
  summary(i)$avg.width
})
```

I had to subsample the data in order to generate the distance matrix for the generation of the silhouette scores because I have ~ 500k cells. Does anyone know why I could be getting only negative silhouette scores for the SOM grids? Should I try non square SOM grids? Should I not aggregate my flow cytometry data prior to running flowSOM (merging of all different timepoints/conditions)? I am currently trying to optimize for the learning rates as well as neighborhood functions..

Any help would be much appreciated.